# Can I change the datatype of a string field in my firestore database into timestamp automatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ttl

I want to create a time-to-live policy based on a date given in one field of my database entry. To do that, this field has to have the datatype "timestamp". But actually it is a string.

Can I change this wrong data type for all incoming database entries with the specific field name (let's say "expiration_time") automatically?

Maybe I have to define a Cloud Function for that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firestore to change a string field to a timestamp. You will have to write code that uses the API to [reads all documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) (possibly with [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)) and then [updates each document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) in turn (or possibly in [batches or transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)).